# Revert back or Pick and choose what changes you want in the TeamCity build

Tags: build, tfs, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have couple of developers changes and they are all checked in to source control. Team city build is failing because of one of the developers changes. Since I already ran the build with both developers changes, how do I revert back to what it was originally (before two changes state)..what I want to do basically is, since it was a successful build until yesterday, I want to go back to that build, so that at least  the website is functioning properly and then just run the build with only one developer changes and not the ones that messed up the build.. thanks for the help. Can I do this with teamcity..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a "history" build in TeamCity, selecting a change in the Custom run build dialog (click on ellipsis of the "Run..." button). If you want then use the artifacts in other builds, you can use "Promote" action from the finished build's "Build Actions".

Or you can use a usual approach to revert the changes in the version control and trigger a new build in TeamCity manually.